# Remove Content controls after adding text using open xml

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

By the help of some very kind community members here I managed to programatically  create a function to replace text inside content controls in a Word document using open xml. After the document is generated it removes the formatting of the text after I replace the text.

Any ideas on how I can still keep the formatting in word and remove the content control tags ?

This is my code:

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
{

    var mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "FirstName", _firstName);
    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "LastName", _lastName);
    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "WorkPhoe", _workPhone);
    ReplaceTags(mainPart, "JobTitle", _jobTitle);

    mainPart.Document.Save();
    SaveFile(mem);
}

private static void ReplaceTags(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName,    string tagValue)
{
    //grab all the tag fields
    IEnumerable<SdtBlock> tagFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName);

    foreach (var field in tagFields)
    {
        //remove all paragraphs from the content block
        field.SdtContentBlock.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
        //create a new paragraph containing a run and a text element
        Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
        Run newRun = new Run();
        Text newText = new Text(tagValue);
        newRun.Append(newText);
        newParagraph.Append(newRun);
        //add the new paragraph to the content block
        field.SdtContentBlock.Append(newParagraph);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the style is a tricky problem as there could be more than one style applied to the text you are trying to replace. What should you do in that scenario?

Assuming a simple case of *one* style (but potentially over many `Paragraphs`, `Runs` and `Texts`) you could keep the first `Text` element you come across per `SdtBlock` and place your required value in that element then delete any further `Text` elements from the `SdtBlock`. The formatting from the first `Text` element will then be maintained. Obviously you can apply this theory to any of the `Text` blocks; you don't have to necessarily use the first. The following code should show what I mean:

```
private static void ReplaceTags(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName, string tagValue)
{
    IEnumerable<SdtBlock> tagFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName);

    foreach (var field in tagFields)
    {
        IEnumerable<Text> texts = field.SdtContentBlock.Descendants<Text>();

        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count(); i++)
        {
            Text text = texts.ElementAt(i);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                text.Text = tagValue;
            }
            else
            {
                text.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When text includes paragraph, <p>Text</p>, the text is not added to the document file, but single value texts are added and they keep the style they got. Any idea how I can keep multi text value text added also with the style intact?

Comment: By "Text" do you mean the text being replaced or the text you are replacing it with? I've tested both scenarios and I can't get either to fail with the above code.

Comment: Sorry, bad explanation. The text is added/replaced to the content control, but with html-encoding, like this <p>some awsome text</p> <P>Yo yo<P>. I tried to remove the html-encoding, but then of course it will all come in the same line without the paragraph, so trying to sort out how to have html-encoded text without showing the html-tags.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense. The trouble is the Docx format is *XML* not HTML so the output you are seeing is what I'd expect. I think you'd be better off using the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29099130/3791802) but for each <p> element you have create a new `Paragraph`, `Run` and `Text`. You can use `InsertAfter` to insert each paragraph after the previous one. If you assign the `RunProperties` to each `Run` you'll keep your styles as well.

Comment: That sounds complicated. As you must have figured out by now, I have not yet quite understood all this stuff with open XML sddt, runs etc. :). Is it possible to cast the code to some XML or run it through a RegEx before inserting it in to the content control ?

Comment: Hi @Ilyas, I'm not too sure to be honest. I guess you could use something like the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML (I would avoid using Regex). Alternatively you could take a look at a converter such as [this one](https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/). I've never tried it so I've no idea what it's like to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will try searching a bit more, and test this one out also.