# How to keep style on open xml documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using open XML(Microsoft Word - .docx) as a file template to automatically generate other documents. In the template document I have defined content controls, and I have written code to replace content in these content controls.

The content is replaced and the documents are generated, but I am struggling with keeping the style. In Word, when inspecting properties of the content control, I have checked the checbox for "Use a style to format text into the empty control: style", and also checked for "Remove content controls when content are edited". This doesn't seem to have any impact when documents are generated by code.

[image: Here is how I set the properties of the content control in Word]
This is my code (which a community member here was kind enough to help with) for replacing the data in the content controls. Any ideas what I should do in order to keep the formatting? The formatting is simple text formatting, like size and font. Please advice:

```
    private static void ReplaceTags(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName, string tagValue)
    {
        //grab all the tag fields
        var tagFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
            (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName);

        foreach (var field in tagFields)
        {
            //remove all paragraphs from the content block
            field.SdtContentBlock.RemoveAllChildren<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>();
            //create a new paragraph containing a run and a text element
            var newParagraph = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph();
            var newRun = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run();
            var newText = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(tagValue);
            newRun.Append(newText);
            newParagraph.Append(newRun);
            //add the new paragraph to the content block
            field.SdtContentBlock.Append(newParagraph);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you assign a style to the content control a new `RunProperties` element is added under the `SdtProperties`. For example, if I assign a new style called `Style1` I can see the following XML is generated:

```
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="Style1" />
        </w:rPr>
    <w:alias w:val="LastName" />
    <w:tag w:val="LastName" />
    ....
```

You need to grab this value and assign it to the new `Paragraph` you are creating, add the `Paragraph` at the same level as the `SdtBlock` and then remove the `SdtBlock` which is what Word does when you select the "Remove content control when contents are edited" option. The `RunProperties` are the `<w:rPr>` element. The following should do what you're after.

```
private static void ReplaceTags(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName, string tagValue)
{
    //grab all the tag fields
    IEnumerable<SdtBlock> tagFields = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where
        (r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName);

    foreach (var field in tagFields)
    {
        //grab the RunProperties from the SdtBlcok
        RunProperties runProp = field.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<RunProperties>();

        //create a new paragraph containing a run and a text element
        Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
        Run newRun = new Run();
        if (runProp != null)
        {
            //assign the RunProperties to our new run
            newRun.Append(runProp.CloneNode(true));
        }
        Text newText = new Text(tagValue);
        newRun.Append(newText);
        newParagraph.Append(newRun);
        //insert the new paragraph before the field we're going to remove
        field.Parent.InsertBefore(newParagraph, field);

        //remove the SdtBlock to mimic the Remove content control when contents are edited option
        field.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi again, and thanks a million for your awsome coding help and very good explanation.  The code worked with regards to keeping style, but I got a new problem along the way :). When running this code, it keeps the styling intact, but after input of new text inside the content control, the text is placed at the bottom of the page. I had it on top. Any ideas how to make it keep it's position `? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @Ilyas. The line `field.Parent.AppendChild(newParagraph);` was adding the new paragraph at the end of the document. I've edited the answer to use `field.Parent.InsertBefore(newParagraph, field);` which will add it before the content control (which then gets deleted, so essentially it's at the same point as the content control was)

Comment: Excellent piece of code! You can even use this to keep the same format when creating multiple lines within the same paragraph, by calling the following within a loop:                    RunProperties runProps = newRun.AppendChild(new RunProperties());
                    Break linebreak = new Break();
                    runProps.Append(linebreak);